# Store data programatically in django database once and exclude from running each time server starts

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I want to store fetched data from URL in database of Django but don't want execution of this code each time server runs. What is good way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there any special reason for fetched from url? You can use fixture for an alternative way.

Comment: @kamilyr Thanks! That is what I was looking for. I was not aware of Data Migration.

Comment: You are welcome :)